# PHP & Mysql- How to sort and display specific data from Mysql with two id

Tags: php, html, mysql

example:

| titletbl | year | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | 2020 | research |
| title2 | 2021 | research |
| title3 | 2020 | program |
| title4 | 2020 | research |

I want to sort it and display only year: '2020' and type named: 'research'

Output should display:

```
------------------------------
title1  |   2020   | research
--------|----------|----------
title4  |   2020   | research
------------------------------
```

Comment: just a simple query will do. What did you attempt ? (show your code)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question..you can insert your code here
Perhaps this will solve your problem

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","your_pass","your_db");
  $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE year='2020' AND type='research' ORDER BY id DESC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
     echo $row['titletbl']." | ".$row['year']." | ".$row['type']."<br />";
    }
```